# Music not playing in Gtk3/Gstreamer app

Tags: python, gtk, gstreamer, gtk3

I have looked at this tutorial,http://lzone.de/media+player+with+gstreamer+and+pygi, on how to stream audio from the web using Gtk3 and Gstreamer.  I have working code minus the ability for actual music to be played. I need help, I'm new to making apps, but I think the issues stems from self.player.set_property('uri', self.uri) not doing its magic to fetch the music from the url self.uri = 'http://mp3channels.webradio.antenne.de/chillout'

Here is my source:

```
import sys, os, pygtk
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject
from gi.repository import GLib
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Gst
GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)
```

class PlaybackInterface():

```
def __init__(self):
    self.playing = False
# A free example sound track
    self.uri = 'http://mp3channels.webradio.antenne.de/chillout'
# GTK window and widgets
    self.window = Gtk.Window()
    self.window.set_size_request(300,50)
    vbox = Gtk.Box(Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 0)
    vbox.set_margin_top(3)
    vbox.set_margin_bottom(3)
    self.window.add(vbox)
    self.playButtonImage = Gtk.Image()
    self.playButtonImage.set_from_stock("gtk-media-play", Gtk.IconSize.BUTTON)
    self.playButton = Gtk.Button.new()
    self.playButton.add(self.playButtonImage)
    self.playButton.connect("clicked", self.playToggled)
    Gtk.Box.pack_start(vbox, self.playButton, False, False, 0)
    self.slider = Gtk.HScale()
    self.slider.set_margin_left(6)
    self.slider.set_margin_right(6)
    self.slider.set_draw_value(False)
    self.slider.set_range(0, 100)
    self.slider.set_increments(1, 10)
    Gtk.Box.pack_start(vbox, self.slider, True, True, 0)
    self.label = Gtk.Label(label='0:00')
    self.label.set_margin_left(6)
    self.label.set_margin_right(6)
    Gtk.Box.pack_start(vbox, self.label, False, False, 0)
    self.window.show_all()

    # GStreamer Setup
    self.player = Gst.ElementFactory.make('playbin', None)
    self.player.set_property('uri', self.uri)
    # Set properties
    # bus = self.player.get_bus()
    # bus.connect("message", self.on_message)
    # self.player.connect("about-to-finish",  self.on_finished)

def on_message(self, bus, message):
    t = message.type
    if t == Gst.Message.EOS:
        self.player.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        self.playing = False
    elif t == Gst.Message.ERROR:
        self.player.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        err, debug = message.parse_error()
        print "Error: %s" % err, debug
        self.playing = False

    self.updateButtons()

def on_finished(self, player):
    self.playing = False
    self.slider.set_value(0)
    self.label.set_text("0:00")
    self.updateButtons()

def play(self):
    self.player.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    GObject.timeout_add(1000, self.updateSlider)

def stop(self):
    self.player.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)

def playToggled(self, w):
    self.slider.set_value(0)
    self.label.set_text("0:00")

    if(self.playing == False):
        self.play()
    else:
        self.stop()

    self.playing=not(self.playing)
    self.updateButtons()

def updateSlider(self):

    if(self.playing == False):
        return False # cancel timeout
        try:
            if self.IS_GST010:
                nanosecs = self.player.query_position(Gst.Format.TIME)[2]
                duration_nanosecs = self.player.query_duration(Gst.Format.TIME)[2]
            else:
                nanosecs = self.player.query_position(Gst.Format.TIME)[1]
                duration_nanosecs = self.player.query_duration(Gst.Format.TIME)[1]
                        # block seek handler so we don't seek when we set_value()
                        # self.slider.handler_block_by_func(self.on_slider_change)
                duration = float(duration_nanosecs) / Gst.SECOND
                position = float(nanosecs) / Gst.SECOND
                self.slider.set_range(0, duration)
                self.slider.set_value(position)
                self.label.set_text ("%d" % (position / 60) + ":%02d" % (position % 60))

        except Exception as e:
# pipeline must not be ready and does not know position
            print e
            pass
        return True

def updateButtons(self):
    if(self.playing == False):
        self.playButtonImage.set_from_stock("gtk-media-play", Gtk.IconSize.BUTTON)
    else:
        self.playButtonImage.set_from_stock("gtk-media-stop", Gtk.IconSize.BUTTON)



player = PlaybackInterface()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Are there any errors on the command line?

Comment: The GUI appears on screem but terminal reads `Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!`

Comment: I am running OS Yosemite, idk if it has to something with X-Windows?

Comment: Maybe you're testing with different code than you what you posted but that is not working code -- updateSlider() at least has issues like referencing IS_GST010 that does not exist and wrong indenting. The playback part works however (on linux). Maybe double check that your gstreamer installation is fine and can actually play the relevant format?

Comment: It is an issue with a Gstreamer dependency, gnutls.  Fixing this problem has turned out to be problematic at the moment, using Homebrew...https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/36323

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gstreamer has a lot of dependencies.  Peep the link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Psychtoolbox-3/Psychtoolbox-3/beta/Psychtoolbox/PsychDocumentation/GStreamer.m.  I uploaded working code on my Github account (At least on my machine) that will play and stop an audio stream from an http source. https://github.com/jchiefelk/musicplayer